# LIGHTTPD - Page NOT found!

Tags: lighttpd

I have an index.php page but I continuing to get 404 not found if I digit Www.mywebsite.com/

This is the log:

> ***.***.***.*** www.MYWEBSITE.com - [26/Apr/2011:09:56:33 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; it) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10

The page exists, but I get 404 not found.

What should I check?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start checking the **root** directory for *lighthttpd* the default page sent (maybe is index.html and not index.php) and **file permissions** and the user running lighthttpd.

Then I'd check the php configuration (`php.ini`) and if php is actually processing the php pages.

Comment: I've checked... the problem are the permissions.

Comment: for each vhosts i create user1:group1   user2:group2   etc etc. but lighttpd run with lighttpd:lighttpd... is not good this layout?

Comment: That is good for splitting the security among the different vhosts, but the **web server needs** at least **reading access** to the files to actually serve them.

Comment: yes, correct, but if I set these permissions 744, ALL the users of the server can read the website's files. I don't think it's really sure. How to set these permissions?

Comment: @Damiano other option can be make the files from the vhosts owned by the **group** `lighttpd`, and give `rwxr-----` permissions to the files and `rwxr-x---` to the directories, this way you will limit the reading access between vhosts to the members of `lighttpd` group. If you don't need to separate vhosts in groups for any other reason (like project separation or something like that) this can be a good solution for you.

Comment: you mean: website1:lighttpd - website2:lighttpd - website3:lighttpd ? in this mode all the vhosts can read themself no? they have the same group. No?

Comment: @Damiano, check your other question for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this in Debian/Ubuntu family distros:

```
cd /etc/lighttpd/conf-available &
lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi-php &
service lighttpd restart &
apt-get install php-cgi &
service lighttpd restart
```